# Trouble Accessing Specific Version of Apex for Machine Learning

Tags: git, machine-learning, github, apex

I am currently trying to run the Machine Learning Model at: https://github.com/facebookresearch/swav

Within this link, a specific version of Apex is required:
https://github.com/facebookresearch/swav/issues/18

Their suggested solution is:

```
git clone "https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex"
cd apex
git checkout 4a1aa97e31ca87514e17c3cd3bbc03f4204579d0
python setup.py install --cuda_ext

python -c 'import apex; from apex.parallel import LARC' # should run and return nothing
python -c 'import apex; from apex.parallel import SyncBatchNorm; print(SyncBatchNorm.__module__)' # should run and return apex.parallel.optimized_sync_batchnorm
```

However, when I ran `git checkout 4a1aa97e31ca87514e17c3cd3bbc03f4204579d0`, I get the error, `fatal: reference is not a tree`.

Are there any workarounds for obtaining the specific apex version?

Thank you.

Edit:

Here is the command I used to run the Machine Learning Model.

```
!python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=8 main_swav.py \
--data_path /path/to/imagenet/train \
--epochs 400 \
--base_lr 0.6 \
--final_lr 0.0006 \
--warmup_epochs 0 \
--batch_size 32 \
--size_crops 224 96 \
--nmb_crops 2 6 \
--min_scale_crops 0.14 0.05 \
--max_scale_crops 1. 0.14 \
--use_fp16 true \
--freeze_prototypes_niters 5005 \
--queue_length 3840 \
--epoch_queue_starts 15
```

Comment: `git checkout 4a1aa97e31ca87514e17c3cd3bbc03f4204579d0` works for me. There is something wrong with your clone. Remove the directory `apex` and try cloning again. Any errors during cloning?

Comment: I'm still having a problem after removing the directory ```apex```. When I run the machine learning command, I get the error ```fatal: reference is not a tree: 4a1aa97e31ca87514e17c3cd3bbc03f4204579d0```. It seems like the machine learning model could not find the module apex, ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apex.parallel'```.